# non deterministic space hierarchy

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, space-complexity

I want to prove the non deterministic space hierarchy theorem.

Let $f(n),g(n)\geq\log n$ be space constructible functions such that $f(n)=o(g(n))$, **Prove**:

$$NSPACE(f(n))\subsetneq NSPACE(g(n))$$

I feel that the standard way of constructing a TM that takes as an input a TM and simulates the machine on itself, then flipping the output won't work because the input is a nondetrministic TM maybe. Can someone suggest a hint?

Comment: Take a look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I actually looked there but their change of proof from the deterministic proof, is not clear since they change stage 4 and know it is not clear why L is still acceptable in NSPACE(g(n)), I mean can you explain why their language L is acceptable in NSPACE(g(n)), because their machine is wrong.

Comment: Did you notice that they changed the language $L$?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Wikipedia proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem) for the non-deterministic *doesn't* flip the output. It considers the language
$$ L = \{ (\langle M \rangle, 1^t) : \text{$M$ accepts $(\langle M \rangle, 1^t)$ in space $g(|(\langle M \rangle, 1^t)|)$} \}. $$
This language is in $\mathsf{NSPACE}(g)$. The [Immerman–Szelepcsényi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immerman%E2%80%93Szelepcs%C3%A9nyi_theorem) shows that if $L \in \mathsf{NSPACE}(f)$ then also $\overline{L} \in \mathsf{NSPACE}(f)$, which leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an elaboration of the proof noted above.  Consider the following algorithm:

A(x) {

Step 1: If x is not of the form $(M,1^{t})$ for some 
           nondeterministic Turing machine $M$ and integer $t$, reject.

Step 2: Compute $q = 2^{g(n)}$ where $n$ is the length of $x$.
     / *  Needs $O(g(n))$ deterministic space, assuming $g$ is constructible */

Step 3: Using a universal Turing machine, simulate $M$ on $x$ for $q$ steps. If $M$ accepts $x$,  accept $x$.  Otherwise, reject $x$.
   / *  This simulation requires only $O(g(n))$ space */
}

Claim: $L(A)$ is not equal to $L(M)$ for any $O(f(n))$ space non deterministic 
       Turing machine if $f(n) = o(g(n))$ and $f(n)$ is constructible.

Proof: For the sake of contradiction, assume that a non deterministic Turing
       machine $M$ accepts $L(A)$ in $O(f(n))$ space.  Then, by 
       Immerman-Szelepscsenyi theorem, there exists a machine $N$ that accepts 
       the complement of $L$ in $O(f(n))$ space.

Consider a string $x$ of the form $x = (N, 1^{t})$ of length $n$ such that $t$ is large enough to ensure that the simulation of $N$ on input $x$ in step 3 of the algorithm runs to completion on all computational paths of $N$.

Now suppose $(N, 1^{t})\in L(A)$.  By Step 3 of the algorithm, this means that $N$ accepts $(N, 1^{t})$ on at least one computational path - that is, $(N, 1^{t})\in L(N)$.   However, both $A$ and $N$ cannot accept the input $(N, 1^{t})$ because of our assumption that $L(N)$ is the complement of $L(A)$.

Hence, we conclude that $A$ does not accept $(N, 1^{t})$. But this too is contradictory. By Step 3 of the algorithm, $N$ must reject  $(N, 1^{t})$ on all computational paths. In other words, $N$ must reject $(N, 1^{t})$.  But both $A$ and $N$ cannot reject $(N, 1^{t})$ as $L(N)$ was assumed to the the complement of $L(A)$.

We conclude that our assumption that $M$ accepts $L(A)$ is contradictory and that $L(A)$ is different from the language accepted by any non deterministic Turing machine that uses $O(f(n))$ space for any $f(n)=o(g(n))$.